# How to remove the permission warning "Read and change all your data on the websites you visit"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome extension to provide additional functionality on my web site.

While adding my extension a user seed the message that the extension would be able to "Read and change all your data on the websites you visit".

How can I remove this permission?

Currently I haven't finalized the domain of site. Can I use some other mechanism to recognize my site (instead of domain)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Domain names are the only way to specify a specific site.  If you don't know the domain yet, then [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) are your best bet.

See also https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#warnings for descriptions of what causes warnings.  Per that, it can be caused by any of the following:

- "debugger" permission
- "pageCapture" permission
- "proxy" permission
- A match pattern in the "permissions" field that matches all hosts
- A "content_scripts" field with a "matches" entry that matches all hosts
- "devtools_page"

Usually, it is a wildcard match pattern in permissions, e.g. `http://*/*`.  If you have a browser action or page action, then you can use [Active Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission to be able to access the page content without requesting permission to the specific site.

Comment: Don't miss that `tabCapture` permission also causes this warning.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in full control of the website and the extension, you could use [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable#external-webpage) to enhance your website. This manifest key allows code on your website to initiate and maintain a communication channel between the website and your extension. Then you can implement the platform-independent parts (e.g. UI with HTML & CSS) in your website, delegate the Chrome-specific parts to the extension, and use the [messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between the page and extension.

The warning that users receive will be less scary:

> Permissions:
>
> - Communicate with cooperating websites

---

If your extension doesn't need to run on the website, but only needs to be able to send HTTP requests to your website (e.g. via an API), then you could add [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to the website to allow the extension to make requests.

---

You could also [use optional permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667112/optionally-inject-content-script/26677279#26677279) to support new sites via content scripts. With this method, Chrome doesn't show any warnings upon installation. A disadvantage of this method is that your users have to approve another permission request before they can use your extension on your website.