# chrome.tabs.executeScript not working inside chrome.tabs.onUpdated callback

Tags: google-chrome-extension

See comments in code below:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  // ################# This works without any problems
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: '!!window.LoadedFlag'
    }, function (hasContentJs) { ... });


  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    //  ################# This throws error:
    // Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript:
    // Cannot access contents of url "http://localhost:3000/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: '!!window.LoadedFlag'
    }, function (hasContentJs) { ... });
```

I'm I not allowed to do `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in a callback to specifically `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` ?

My use-case is that I need to run a startup script on every page refresh but only if my extension has been enabled.

manifest.json:

```
"permissions" : [
    "activeTab"
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
```

Comment: Did you reload your extension after setting the new permissions? And using onUpdated is not the best way to optionally inject content scripts. For better alternatives, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667112/optionally-inject-content-script/26677279#26677279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, just a simple misstake of reloading the extension. When making changes to the .js files, it's enough just to hit `cmd+r` to reload it. It looks like when changing the `manifest.json` I needed to go to `chrome://extentions` and do a harder reload. Thanks to Rob W for the tip in the comment and link to better alternatives.