# Enable/Disable "content_scripts.css" in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

For example:

```
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ]
  ...
```

I would like to inject this stylesheet by default. Which is business as usual.

I would also like to `enable/disable`, when the user when the user `clicks` on the icon in the toolbar.

Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667112/optionally-inject-content-script/26677279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement this in one of my extensions as well. I used a checkbox in my `popup.html` to manipulate `chrome.storage`, which would store whether the state was enabled or disabled.

The content script was always running, but would check [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) first before performing any actions. Feel free to refer to my repository [here](https://github.com/noamhacker/quick-overflow), particularly `inject.js`.

This isn't the only way to do it, but it was pretty simple for me to implement. Note that you can't use `localstorage` because the content script exists in a separate environment.

Comment: Thanks! Though it didn't answer my question completely, it did made me aware of `chrome.storage`. And I solved it in my way utilizing `chrome.storage`, `browserAction`, `executeScript`. Accepted the answer. :) You can see my implementation at [focus-indicator](https://github.com/sarbbottam/focus-indicator/tree/master/src/js).

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for adding details of your implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround.

manifest.json

```json
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "my_style.css"
]
...
```

content_script.js

```js
const target = document.head || document.documentElement;

const link  = document.createElement('link');
link.id = 'my_style_css';
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('my_style.css');

target.appendChild(link);
```

to disable

```js
link.disabled = true;

//or

document.getElementById('my_style_css').disabled = true;
```