# Is there a way to make chrome extensions run independently between tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple chrome extension that reads text from a webpage and displays it on the popup. When I have multiple different tabs open and I switch between them, the value in every tab's popup gets changed to value of the most recently opened tab. How can make each tab's popup display its own text?

Comment: Depends on how that text is displayed. For chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText you can specify `tabId` in parameters, see the documentation. Otherwise you should show your code and manifest.json in the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Agree with wOxxOm that this question requires a minimal code snippet demonstrating the failure mode, in order for people to offer meaningful feedback. If you're not familiar with the idea, this means "create the simplest possible piece of code that still breaks in the way you describe."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: load different content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563379/chrome-extension-load-different-content-scripts)